# Scale up MessageBox

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've got zooming functionality in my application that works great, but when I open a MessageBox, the message box doesn't appear at the same zoomed level as the rest of the interface. Is there anyway I can scale the MessageBox along with the rest of my program? Or will I have to create a custom message box class that allows this?

Thanks. Let me know if I need to explain anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create a custom dialog to do this.  I'd probably just create a window and then [show it as a dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx).

Comment: I'm trying this out now. It seems like its working. I'm just going to leave this open for a little longer to see what other ideas are out there. Thanks

Comment: I always try to use a MessageBox if possible, but if there are any additional requirements (e.g. custom buttons, different layout, etc), then I find I'm forced to just create a custom Window myself.  Fortunately they've made it pretty easy :)